# Set picklist Value as default value in a field on sales a engagement Runtime Object

Tags: xml, object, runtime, metadata

I managed to **customize** the standardValueSet of the CompletionDisposition field on **ActionCadencetracker** runtime object, but I failed to assign values as a default value using metadata xml:

```
<fullName>My Value</fullName>
      <default>true</default>
 <label>Completed Cadence</label>
```

I deployed the updated fields values **metadata** back using **Workbench** successfully, but on the **UI**, the field's value is not being set as default.

If the above is not **doable**, can we have the **completionDisposition** field as required so the **Rep** must select a **disposition** value before removing the target?
Any help is highly appreciated!